# Spring Cloud microservice deployment in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to develop a Spring Cloud microservice and need to deploy in AWS cloud. I am new to Spring Cloud and AWS. I would like to open a EC2 instance and like to deploy using Elastic Beanstalk environment wizard.

When I am exploring how to create EC instance and configuration, I found that the documentation explaining EC2 and EC2 container service. Here I need to deploy my service in Java environment and Tomcat as service structure. So I am confused about EC2 and EC2 container service. Which one is suitable for my criteria and requirement? EC2 or Ec2 container service for deploying my service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 container service is to be used if you want to run container systems like Docker. Are you comfortable using Docker containers?

If you want to use standard virtual machine; use EC2 instance. Your requirement of deploying microservice can be achieved using any of EC2 instance or EC2 container service. What is important is your comfort level.

Comment: When I readed about EC2 and EC2 containers I totally confused. Because lot of deployment options using only EC2 and also using EC2 container services. Since I new to cloud and services platform.And also did not got clarity with docker container service running with AWS. I am beginner with cloud and AWS. So I facing lot of doubts in deployment. Since I now converting one monolithic web application into microservices structure with front-end angular. So now I need to deploy 20 to 25 services for my web application.

Comment: Hi Prince .. I completely get that .. As mentioned ; you can develop micro-services with containers like Dockers or without containers.. What is your choice ? Do you know Docker ?

Comment: Yes.Currently I am exploring that section. Dockers.